# Get value from attribute

Tags: php, xml

I got a XML tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tree>
    <message name="login_form_empty">Vergeten in te vullen</message>
    <message name="signup_form_empty">Vergeten in te vullen</message>
    <message name="forgotpass_form_empty">Vergeten in te vullen</message>
</tree>
```

Is it possible to get the value from example: login_form_empty?

Thanks!

Comment: Answer- Yes,Is it possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have a look at the PHP documentation: http://php.net/simplexml

Answer (score 1):

Use xPath to access the XML values. Something like this xPath statement should work:

```
//tree/message/@name
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, use a XML->object converter like [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) and use xPath to find the right elements.

```
<?php 
$string = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tree>
    <message name="login_form_empty">Vergeten in te vullen</message>
    <message name="signup_form_empty">Vergeten in te vullen</message>
    <message name="forgotpass_form_empty">Vergeten in te vullen</message>
</tree>'; 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
$login_form_empty = $xml->xpath('/tree/message[@name="login_form_empty"]');

foreach ($login_form_empty as $result) {
    echo $result;
}

?>
```